# AWS VPC client endpoint

Tags: amazon-web-services, vpn, vpc

I need a kind of 'point2site' vpn solution in AWS VPC. I choose VPC Client VPN Endpoint. But I found the Client VPN Endpoint is not yet available in Tokyo region.

I want to setup a VPC in us-east-1(North Virginia) region, where Client VPN Endpoint is available. I want to setup my workload VPC in Tokyo region, so I want to setup a VPC peering to connect us-east-1(North Virginia) region and Tokyo region. Is it possible to setup Client VPN Endpoint in us-east-1(North Virginia) region, and then connect to Tokyo region by means of VPC peering?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can create a **VPC Peering** connection between the two regions:

- In **Tokyo**, create a peering connection to the VPC in N. Virginia
- In **N. Virginia**, accept the peering connection
- Update route tables in both VPCs to route traffic via the peering connection

I tested this between Tokyo and N. Virginia and is worked fine.